# Cheapest single-state munis for Maryland

Tags: bonds, municipal-bonds

After researching a while, it seems T Rowe Price offers the lowest expense ratio for Maryland Muni Fund. Does anyone have a different observation?

Comment: Sadly, product recommendations are off-topic.